# How do I sort an array formula column based on date format in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q3b1aFR3Y9oRR0fpJgD9fxSp_3p_EJtK72nPGdI6t3Q/edit?usp=sharing

On the left, there is an array formula that counts the totals and the two uniques on the right. However, as you can see, the sorting is kind of weird, with the dates going from 10 -> 11 -> 9 Feb. What I would like to do is make the dates go from 11 -> 10 -> 9 Feb. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Query function is sorting dates as texts

You can use the DATEVALUE function to create a new sort

---

**Your formula after edit**

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT({G1:I, IF((I1:I<>"")*(COUNTIFS(G1:G&I1:I, G1:G&I1:I, ROW(I1:I), "<="&ROW(I1:I))=1), G1:G&I1:I, ), IF((J1:J<>"")*(COUNTIFS(G1:G&J1:J, G1:G&J1:J, ROW(J1:J), "<="&ROW(J1:J))=1), G1:G&J1:J, ),DATEVALUE(G1:G)}), "select Col1,count(Col1),count(Col4),count(Col5),Col6 where Col1 !='' group by Col1,Col6 order by Col6 desc label count(Col1)'Total', count(Col4)'Unique1', count(Col5)'Unique2',Col6 'Col hide'", 1)),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4")`

---

**Function References**

- [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en)
- [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)